# Open txt file, skip first lines and then monitor a given column of data

Tags: python, file-io

I have a results txt file with some headings, and then lists several results in different columns (separated by spaces). I want to control the execution of the program based on values of a given variable (say 6th column). So I have to skip the first lines and then store in an array the values of the 6th column). How can I do this?

Third try:

STA = Path of file

```
head_lines = 4
i = 0
variableX = []
if path.exists(STA) and path.isfile(STA) and access(STA, R_OK):
    inputFile = open(STA,'r')
    for n, line in enumerate(inputFile):
        if n > head_lines:
            cols = line.split()
            if len(cols) == 9:
                variableX.append(cols[7])
                i = i+1
    for i in range(len(variableX)):
        if i>=3 and float(variableX[i-2])<=0 and \
        float(variableX[i-1])<=0 and float(variableX[i])<=0:
            try:
                os.system('abaqus terminate job=file_name')
                time.sleep(1)
                os.remove('path to file')
            except:
                print "No such file"
    inputFile.close()
```

Comment: This is quite trivial. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes. This is quite trivial. Post some code that you've tried and we can show you how to fix it

Comment: Hi! I'm a newbie to python so basically from scratch...

Comment: I'll try to come up with something

Comment: How are the column separated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
inputFile = open(path,'r')
for n, line in enumerate(inputFile):
    if n > given_number:
       variableX = line.split(' ')[5]
inputFile.close()
```

Edit based on the new information provided:

Since you have a header, then the data and then one extra line, you can skip the header lines and then process only the ones that have the right amount of columns.

```
inputFile = open(path,'r')
head_lines = 4
for n, line in enumerate(inputFile):
    if n > head_lines:
       cols = line.split()
       if len(cols) == 9:               
           variableX = cols[7]
           # do whatever you need with variableX
inputFile.close()
```

Comment: It does not work for me. IndexError: list index out of range
#*     variableX = line.split(' ')[7]

Comment: That error means in that line there aren't 8 columns (meaning by columns words separated by one space). If there are lines with less columns you need to take that into acount. You can do the split first, count the items with `len()` and then assign the column you need in each case.

Comment: The problem is that after a few lines there's a line with just one column. So I've changed my code to check the size of the data set, but it doesn't work because the second for cycle is never called. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Why are you looping twice through the lines of the file? I don't understand what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I'm looping twice in order to get the size of the data set. As I said there's a part of the txt file following the end of the data set which is not of interest and does not have 8 columns (that's why the error above was showing). To skip this I think the bets way could be to frame the loop to assign a value to variableX. I'm open to alternatives! :)

Comment: There's probably a way to do it without reading the file twice. If you could post some sample of the data you're working with (with the lines you want and the ones you want to discard), maybe I could get a better idea.

Comment: Posted above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: However I'd like to store all values of column 8 in my VariableX array so that I can compare the last value with the previous ones... I've tried variableX[i] = cols[7] i = i+1 but I get an error "NameError: name 'variableX' is not defined". I googled and nothing applicable shows up.

Comment: Hi Andrés, I've a new very basic question! Sorry!